# Shortest curve interpolating points with a constraint on the curvature

Tags: shortest-path, planning

I'm looking for a method for determining a path for a UAV that interpolates a set of input locations, with a constraint on maximum curvature and given an initial velocity vector.

The cost (length) of the path should be as small as possible.

I know a little bit about Dubins curves but that's in 2D and only for two points.

Comment: Apparently Dubins curves can also be extended to 3D and to multiple points, eg. GDSP problem. It's all in the literature and algorithms are described there, though there is no optimal one.